# Galaxy S2 can't plug in to laptop with usb correctly

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-galaxy-s-2

Why when i try to plug in with the cable Galaxy S2 and a laptop, it's not showing any new partition that must be for the galaxy.I get a successful conection on the phone, but it's not having a popup window, for example to ask me if i want to charge my battery from the laptop or to do some stuff with the files.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Settings -> Wireless and network -> USB utilities` and choose "Connect storage to PC".

Or, if you want to automatically sync files via wifi from phone to your Dropbox or FTP account you can use a super app called "RealSync". You can get this app [here](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.designoid.therealsync.pro&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5kZXNpZ25vaWQudGhlcmVhbHN5bmMucHJvIl0).